# Joining and sorting strings: how to turn week menu into shopping list?

Tags: google-sheets

Every Sunday I define with my girlfriend a menu for the coming week. We use Google Sheets for that: each cell is a comma-separated list of products to prepare a meal. We enter those data manually. Then I manually create a shopping list of products to buy, going through the menu. How can I automate this process?

I was thinking about the following *algorithm*:

1. *Concate* products from selected cells into an array.
2. *Split* each element of the array by comma, so that the result is an array of arrays of single products.
3. *Flattenize* the output of the previous step, i.e., turn the array of arrays into 1-dimensional array of products.
4. *Remove duplicate* products or at least sort them lexically.
5. *Join* all products into a single string with comma-separated elements, so that the final output can be displayed in a single cell.

Here's an example of how it works with input (selected menu) and output (shopping list). Click the screenshot to go to the original document.

[image: example]

I have programming background (Java), but I am not familiar with Google Sheets abstractions, e.g., whether there's a concept of an array.

Is my algorithm implementable in Google Sheets? What functions should I use?

Comment: How do you get the menu items into gsheets, do you import the html, scrape the data or manually type it in?do you mind creating an example sheet and a desired output tab

Comment: @Datanovice I have updated my question with an example. I enter menu items into gsheets manually.

Comment: I didn't remove the duplicates but you can use =UNIQUE() to do that, try : =ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,trim(split(JOIN(",",B2:B5,C2:C5,D2:D5,E2:E5,F2:F5),",",true,true))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this as an answer, got your desired result (bar the commas), finally got around to testing it.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,TRIM(SPLIT(JOIN(",",B2:B5,C2:C5,D2:D5,E2:E5,F2:F5),",",true,true))))
```

Working backwards,

1. first we join our cells using the `JOIN` command, essentially creating an array.
2. we then pass the `SPLIT` function to split this array.
3. we apply `TRIM` to remove and leading and trailing white space.
4. We use the `TEXTJOIN` command passing `CHAR(10)` (ASCII code for end of line) as our argument.
5. we finish using an `ARRAYFORMULA` which actually is necessary for the `TRIM` function. I'm not 100% sure why, but my guess would be the trim needs to be inside an array to function across a wide-range of cells.

and there you have your groceries.

Sheet as an example.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qONq_DpPdb7h8NYO2LYYlBc74oc_UMFM3Ob-TOZ9pNs/edit

EDIT : Updated Criterion:

the best I could do is pass a `sort` and a `transpose` which sorts the cell but the case-insensitive bit is beyond me, maybe someone else can help?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN("," & CHAR(10),TRUE,sort(TRANSPOSE(trim(split(JOIN(",",B2:B5,C2:C5,D2:D5,E2:E5,F2:F5),",",true,true))))))
```

Comment: Thanks. What would be the way to sort the groceries list? I've tried to enclose `TRIM` function with `SORT` or `SORTN` functions and it didn't work.

Comment: Sort by what alphabetical order?

Comment: Yes, case-insensitive alphabetical order. E.g. "Eggs, Beef, Chicken, Rice, food (15), rice" should become "Beef, Chicken, Eggs, Rice, rice, food (15)".

Comment: I have no idea, especially the case insesntivie bit, will have to play around!